# Will connecting my wallet to my belt loop deter or attract pickpockets?

Tags: money, payment-cards, security

#### Coil Connector to Wallet

A chain would be better, since it can't be surreptitiously cut or clipped, but it's too close to travel time to buy a chain or buy a money belt, so those are off the table for this question.

This coiled plastic thing is pretty strong (I think it would rip through the wallet leather before breaking:

[image: wallet connected through plastic coil]

But if the pickpocket sees this connector and has the means to cut it, would I be better off leaving the coil connection thing at home and not even connecting my wallet to my belt loop?  Obviously, the wallet will be in a front pocket, and if the pants have a zipper pocket, the zipper will be closed.  But in come cases, the front pocket has no zipper.

I rigged-up this coil connector, but then got to thinking, maybe the pickpocket would use the coil to lift the wallet, then clip the plastic, or as suggested in the comments below, clip the belt loop itself.

#### Experience with Pick Pockets

The best answer would be from someone who really knows how pickpockets operate, rather than "thinking logically" without a whole lot of facts or experience to back it up.  I've got a bit of experience getting tapped by pickpockets (carrying a 'dummy' wallet in my back pocket), but always spun around to see them disappear into the crowd without getting even the dummy wallet.  But I'm sure they could "get me", like anyone else, because they are almost more sly than imaginable.

Do you have a lot of experience with pick-pocketing techniques and can say **whether the plastic coil is a good idea or will it be more of a liability than an asset** when considering deterring a pickpocket?

Comment: Not a pickpocket so who knows, but to me that screams HELLO I'M A TARGET! PS The weak point is the belt loop.

Comment: You can buy money belts in airport shops.

Comment: If your destination is credit card friendly considering having no wallet at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say you may be a bit safer *in some situations* (at the expense of looking a bit stupid), but that depends.

At least it would be something unexpected for most pickpockets. What you need to consider is that pickpockets are not after you, specifically, but the *easiest target*. From my (luckily limited) personal experience I can say that when I was pickpocketed/stolen from, it was always because of being an easy target.

That said, "easy target" can vary significantly depending on where you go. In some parts of the world looking Asian may mark you as unsuspecting. In some parts, where mugging is more common, walking alone makes you an easy target. Sometimes playing with you phone in the subway will.

Does the coil make you safer? If the pickpocket sees it and and assumes that someone else is an easier mark, it may. Will it make a big difference either way? Probably not. Can we say for sure? No.

Personally, I'd leave the thing at home; even if it works it'll probably add too little to justify the weirdness of it.

I always recommend to do as the locals do, and not get paranoid just because you are in a different country.

I see two possible scenarios here:

- If you keep a moderate amount of money in your wallet and have a spare ATM card in a separate location, having your wallet nicked should not be the end of the world. In this case the coil wouldn't be worth the trouble (for me).
- On the other hand: If I were forced to lug around my entire travel budget in cash (and/or irreplacable documents), the additional "security" of that coil would be too little for me. I would rather get a money belt at my earliest convenience and not keep the things in my pant pockets at all.

Comment: I got a reply from gene at pickpocket dot com.  He said "Leave it at home and wear a hidden money belt underneath the clothing"